# using boost::property_tree, is it possible to create a xml attribute with a '.' in the name?

Tags: xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using boost 1.51 and have something like this:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree some_tree;
some_tree.put("hello.world.<xmlattr>.foo.bar","4711");
```

I was hoping to get

```
<hello>
  <world foo.bar="4711"/>
</hello>
```

But I only get

```
<hello>
  <world foo=""/>
</hello>
```

Using boost::property_tree, is it possible to create an xml file with an attribute name containing a '.' character or do I need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a separator other than the default `.`. Try this,

```
boost::property_tree::ptree some_tree;
some_tree.put(ptree::path("hello/world/<xmlattr>/foo.bar", '/'),"4711");
```